# worksheet change event will not fire in console application

Tags: vb.net, excel, console-application

I have been trying to develop a console application that will open an existing Excel workbook and write data into the sheet. The data it is gathering is coming from another application called NX, a CAD program. I wrote the console app in VB.NET, using Framework 4.5 and Office 2010. The code works as it should, except for the event based code. I included some functionality that should fire off when a selection change event occurs. I have spent weeks doing research and trying to discover why my event based code will not fire off. The only conclusion I seem to be coming is that the console app is immediately getting closed/completed and not giving "enough time" for the event handler to get kicked.

Here is my code:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Remoting
Imports System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports NXOpen
Imports NXOpen.Assemblies
Imports NXOpen.Utilities
Imports NXOpen.UF


Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop ' import Excel Interop Namespace
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Module remoting_client_test

    Public theSession As Session = DirectCast(Activator.GetObject(GetType(Session), "http://localhost:4567/NXOpenSession"), Session)
    Public ufs As UFSession = DirectCast(Activator.GetObject(GetType(UFSession), "http://localhost:4567/UFSession"), UFSession)
    Public workPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Work
    Public displayPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Display
    Public TagIdentifier As Long
    Public row As Long = 3

    Sub Main()

        Dim myForm As New Form1

        'need to initialize value of excel object variables

        myForm.OpenWorkBook("C:\Path File")

        myForm.ProcessNXData()

    End Sub

    Public Sub DoLog(s As [String])
        Session.GetSession().LogFile.WriteLine(s)
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    End Sub

    Sub Echo(ByVal output As String)

        theSession.ListingWindow.Open()
        theSession.ListingWindow.WriteLine(output)
        theSession.LogFile.WriteLine(output)

    End Sub

    Public Function GetUnloadOption(ByVal dummy As String) As Integer
        Return Session.LibraryUnloadOption.Immediately
    End Function


End Module

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents excel As Excel.Application
    Private WithEvents workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Private WithEvents myWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet


    Public Sub OpenWorkBook(path As String)
        If excel Is Nothing Then
            excel = New Excel.Application
            excel.Visible = True ' user is responsible for closing Excel
            excel.UserControl = True
            excel.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        If workbook IsNot Nothing Then
            FreeCOM(workbook)
        End If
        Dim workbooks As Excel.Workbooks = excel.Workbooks
        workbook = workbooks.Open(path)
        FreeCOM(workbooks)

        If myWorksheet IsNot Nothing Then
            FreeCOM(myWorksheet)
        End If
        Dim Worksheets As Excel.Sheets = workbook.Worksheets

        myWorksheet = CType(Worksheets.Item(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) ' 1 based indexing
        Worksheets("NX Data").Activate()
        myWorksheet = Worksheets("NX Data")

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub FreeCOM(ByVal COMObj As Object, Optional ByVal GCCollect As Boolean = False)
        Try
            If COMObj IsNot Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(COMObj)
            End If
        Finally
            COMObj = Nothing
            If GCCollect Then
                GC.Collect()
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub


    Public Sub ProcessNXData()
        ' This assumes the assembly is loaded.

        Dim dp As Part = theSession.Parts.Display
        Dim row As Long = 3

        theSession.EnableRedo(False)

        Dim nextBody As NXOpen.Tag = NXOpen.Tag.Null

        Do
            Dim t As Integer, st As Integer
            Dim isOcc As Boolean = False
            Dim theProtoTag As NXOpen.Tag = NXOpen.Tag.Null
            Dim owningPart As NXOpen.Tag = nextBody
            Dim partName As String = ""

            ufs.Obj.CycleTypedObjsInPart(dp.Tag, UFConstants.UF_solid_type, nextBody)
            If nextBody.Equals(NXOpen.Tag.Null) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            ufs.Obj.AskTypeAndSubtype(nextBody, t, st)
            If st <> UFConstants.UF_solid_body_subtype Then
                Continue Do
            End If
            isOcc = ufs.Assem.IsOccurrence(nextBody)
            If isOcc.Equals(True) Then
                'Echo("Found occurrence body: " & nextBody.ToString())
                theProtoTag = ufs.Assem.AskPrototypeOfOcc(nextBody)
                ufs.Obj.AskOwningPart(theProtoTag, owningPart)
                ufs.Part.AskPartName(owningPart, partName)
                Echo("Owning Part: " & partName)
            End If

            Dim theNXOM As NXObjectManager = theSession.GetObjectManager
            Dim theObj As NXObject = theNXOM.GetTaggedObject(nextBody)
            Dim theBody As Body = CType(theObj, Body)


            Dim myMeasure As MeasureManager = theSession.Parts.Display.MeasureManager()
            Dim massUnits(4) As Unit

            massUnits(0) = theSession.Parts.Display.UnitCollection.GetBase("Area")
            massUnits(1) = theSession.Parts.Display.UnitCollection.GetBase("Volume")
            massUnits(2) = theSession.Parts.Display.UnitCollection.GetBase("Mass")
            massUnits(3) = theSession.Parts.Display.UnitCollection.GetBase("Length")

            Dim singleBodyArray() As Body = {theBody}
            Dim mb As MeasureBodies = myMeasure.NewMassProperties(massUnits, 1, singleBodyArray)
            mb.InformationUnit = MeasureBodies.AnalysisUnit.PoundFoot

            Dim centroidalPoint As Point3d = mb.Centroid()
            Echo("Centroid: " & centroidalPoint.X & "  " & centroidalPoint.Y & "  " & centroidalPoint.Z)
            Echo("  ")

            'get parent tag
            Dim parentTag As Tag
            ufs.Assem.AskParentComponent(theBody.Tag, parentTag)
            Dim bodyComp As Component = theSession.GetObjectManager.GetTaggedObject(parentTag)
            'get root name
            Dim c As ComponentAssembly = workPart.ComponentAssembly

            excel.Cells(2, 2) = theBody.OwningPart.Leaf

            excel.Cells(2, 3).value = c.RootComponent.GetStringAttribute("DB_PART_NAME")

            'find attribute data
            If bodyComp.HasUserAttribute("DB_PART_NAME", NXObject.AttributeType.String, -1) = True Then
                excel.Cells(row, 3) = bodyComp.GetStringAttribute("DB_PART_NAME")
            End If

            If bodyComp.HasUserAttribute("MF Material", NXObject.AttributeType.String, -1) = True Then
                excel.Cells(row, 7) = bodyComp.GetStringAttribute("MF Material")
            End If

            If bodyComp.HasUserAttribute("MF NN", NXObject.AttributeType.String, -1) = True Then
                excel.Cells(row, 9) = bodyComp.GetStringAttribute("MF NN")
            End If

            If bodyComp.HasUserAttribute("MF Modifier", NXObject.AttributeType.String, -1) = True Then
                excel.Cells(row, 8) = bodyComp.GetStringAttribute("MF Modifier")
            End If

            If bodyComp.HasUserAttribute("MF Type", NXObject.AttributeType.String, -1) = True Then
                excel.Cells(row, 10) = bodyComp.GetStringAttribute("MF Type")
            End If

            'bounding box 
            Dim bodyLengths(2) As Double
            bodyLengths = GetBoundingBox(theBody)

            'Measures Min/Max of all model parts in assembly 
            Dim bbox(5) As Double
            Dim tagList(0) As NXOpen.Tag
            ufs.Modl.AskBoundingBox(theBody.Tag, bbox)

            'write data to cells
            excel.Cells(row, 2).value = bodyComp.Parent.Prototype.OwningPart.Leaf
            excel.Cells(row, 4).value = bodyComp.Prototype.OwningPart.Leaf
            excel.Cells(row, 11).value = mb.Volume.ToString
            excel.Cells(row, 14).value = centroidalPoint.Z
            excel.Cells(row, 16).value = centroidalPoint.X
            excel.Cells(row, 18).value = centroidalPoint.Y
            excel.Cells(row, 21) = (bbox(0) / 12) 'LCG
            excel.Cells(row, 22) = (bbox(3) / 12)
            excel.Cells(row, 23) = (bbox(2) / 12) 'VCG
            excel.Cells(row, 24) = (bbox(5) / 12)
            excel.Cells(row, 25) = (bbox(1) / 12) 'TCG
            excel.Cells(row, 26) = (bbox(4) / 12)
            excel.Cells(row, 50).value = nextBody.ToString

            row = row + 1

        Loop Until nextBody.Equals(NXOpen.Tag.Null)

    End Sub

    Private Function GetBoundingBox(ByVal solidBody As NXOpen.Body) As Double()

        'AskBoundingBox returns min and max coordinates
        'this function will simply return the box lengths (x, y, z)
        Dim bboxCoordinates(5) As Double
        Dim bboxLengths(2) As Double

        Try
            'get solid body bounding box extents
            ufs.Modl.AskBoundingBox(solidBody.Tag, bboxCoordinates)
            bboxLengths(0) = bboxCoordinates(3) - bboxCoordinates(0)
            bboxLengths(1) = bboxCoordinates(4) - bboxCoordinates(1)
            bboxLengths(2) = bboxCoordinates(5) - bboxCoordinates(2)

            Return bboxLengths

        Catch ex As NXException
            MsgBox(ex.GetType.ToString & " : " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Solid Body Bounds Error!")
            bboxLengths(0) = 0
            bboxLengths(1) = 0
            bboxLengths(2) = 0
            Return bboxLengths
        End Try

    End Function


    Sub Echo(ByVal output As String)
        theSession.ListingWindow.Open()
        theSession.ListingWindow.WriteLine(output)
        theSession.LogFile.WriteLine(output)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetUnloadOption(ByVal arg As String) As Integer
        Return Session.LibraryUnloadOption.Immediately
    End Function
    Public Sub myWorksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) Handles myWorksheet.SelectionChange

        MsgBox("its firing")

        Dim theSession As Session = DirectCast(Activator.GetObject(GetType(Session), "http://localhost:4567/NXOpenSession"), Session)
        Dim ufs As UFSession = DirectCast(Activator.GetObject(GetType(UFSession), "http://localhost:4567/UFSession"), UFSession)

        Dim workPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Work
        Dim dp As Part = theSession.Parts.Display

        'Dim theCompName As String
        Dim theCompTag As NXOpen.Tag = NXOpen.Tag.Null
        Dim RowNum As Long

        RowNum = Target.Row
        TagIdentifier = excel.Cells(RowNum, 50).value()
        ufs.Disp.SetHighlight(TagIdentifier, 1)

        ReleaseComObject(Target)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

        If myWorksheet IsNot Nothing Then
            FreeCOM(myWorksheet)
        End If
        If workbook IsNot Nothing Then
            FreeCOM(myWorksheet)
        End If
        If excel IsNot Nothing Then
            FreeCOM(excel, True)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can somebody please tell me what they think the issue is?

Comment: Could you specify what code should fire the ```myWorksheet_SelectionChange```? Or is the user manually changing the selection on the sheet ```myWorksheet```? When you try e.g. ```myWorksheet.Range("A1").Select``` and after this code ```myWorksheet.Range("A2").Select``` is the event not fired?

Comment: dee, the user will manually select cells on the sheet. Whether I manually select cells, or do it programmatically I get no response. Which is weird because my console app will write data to the sheet with no issues whatsoever. So you would think that it would respond to sheet selection changes.

Comment: Have you tried to catch selection change for the excel application: ```Private Sub xlApp_SheetSelectionChange( _
        ByVal Sh As Object, _
        ByVal Target As Excel.Range) _
        Handles excel.SheetSelectionChange```? Or have you tried to add handler programatically without ```WithEvents``` like this : ```AddHandler myWorksheet.SelectionChange, AddressOf myWorksheet_SelectionChange```?